# getItem with argument is column name

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

My column `col1` is an Array.

I know that `col1.getItem(2)` allows you to access the second argument of the column. Is there a function to access with argument as column `col1.getItem(col2)`  ?

I can create a UDF but I would have to specify which type the array is (and it can be multiple type) so a generic way would be better and welcome !

The UDF I use:

```
  def retrieveByIndexSingle[T : ClassTag](value:Seq[T] ,index:Int,offset:Int=0):T = value(index + offset)

  def retrieveByIndexSingleDUDF = udf((value:Seq[Double] ,index:Int) => {
    retrieveByIndexSingle[Double](value, index)
  })

  def retrieveByIndexSingleSUDF = udf((value:Seq[String] ,index:Int) => {
    retrieveByIndexSingle[String](value, index)
  })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to use SQL expression for example with `expr`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.expr

val df = Seq(
    (Seq("a", "b", "c"), 0), (Seq("d", "e", "f"), 2)
).toDF("col1", "col2")
df.withColumn("col3", expr("col1[col2]")).show
```

```
+---------+----+----+
|     col1|col2|col3|
+---------+----+----+
|[a, b, c]|   0|   a|
|[d, e, f]|   2|   f|
+---------+----+----+
```

or, in Spark 2.4 or later, `element_at` function:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.element_at

df.withColumn("col3", element_at($"col1", $"col2" + 1)).show
```

```
+---------+----+----+
|     col1|col2|col3|
+---------+----+----+
|[a, b, c]|   0|   a|
|[d, e, f]|   2|   f|
+---------+----+----+
```

Please note that at the moment (Spark 2.4) there is inconsistency between these two methods:

- SQL `[]` indexing is 0-based.
- `element_at` indexing is 1-based.